# Javascript/Lodash - Getting unique values in an Array of arrays

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am having a complicated case where I need to have unique values in an array of arrays.

here is what I have right now :

```
var ar = [{
"theFirstArray": [
    [{
        "no": 1
    }, {
        "no": 2
    }, {
        "no": 3
    }, {
        "no": 4
    }, {
        "no": 11
    }]
],

    "theSecondArray": [{
        "no": 3
    },
    {
        "no": 1
    },
    {
        "no": 4
    },
    {
        "no": 9
    },
    {
        "no": 39
    },
    {
        "no": 18
    },
    {
        "no": 19
    }
],

    "theThirdArray": [{
        "no": 20
    }, {
        "no": 12
    }, {
        "no": 10
    }, {
        "no": 9
    }, {
        "no": 16
    }]
  }]
```

What I need to achieve :

```
[{
"theFirstArray":[{"no":1},{"no":2},{"no":3},{"no":4}]
},{
"theSecondArray":[{"no":9}, {"no":39}, {"no":18}, {"no":19}]
},{
"theThirdArray":[{"no":20},{"no":12},{"no":10},{"no":16}]
}]
```

PS. note that I need only to output 4 values in each subarray, and also the value is not repeated in all the array.

I've already tried the following:

```
_.uniqBy(ar, 'no');
```

It's true that I got only the unique values in the result; however, I was not able to get the same wanted structure as I got the following:

```
[{
 theFirstArray:[{"no":1,"no":2,"no":3,"no":4, "no":9, "no":39, "no":18,   "no":19, "no":20,"no":12,"no":10,"no":16}]
}]
```

I've also tried to work with _.map but that didn't work to!

Comment: Are you sure that this is the actual structure of the array because you have object literals that use the same key in the same object ?

Comment: You can not have structures like `{ "no": 1, "no": 2 }`. Object keys are supposed to be unique.

Comment: you can think of "no" like and "idNumber" what supposed to be unique is the value, not the key

Comment: @HamzaL. _"what supposed to be unique is the value, not the key"_ That's not how objects work...

Comment: @Andreas sorry, my mistake, I've just done an edit, please check it now

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
function getUniqueArrays(arr) {
  var uniqAr = [];
  var allArr = [{
    no: null
  }];
  arr.forEach(function(item) {
    var itemKey = Object.keys(item)[0]; 
    var itemArr = _.uniqBy(item[itemKey], 'no');
    var itemArr = _.differenceBy(itemArr, allArr, 'no').slice(0, 4);
    allArr = itemArr.concat(allArr);
    var newItem = {};
    newItem[itemKey] = itemArr;
    uniqAr.push(newItem);
  })

  return uniqAr;
}
```

From your example I presume, you always has only one key in object.

If you always have unique values in every array (that one that contain objects like {no: 1}), than you can get rid off line: 
`var itemArr = _.uniqBy(item[itemKey], 'no');`

Answer (score 0):

Lodash all the things! You can use `reduce` to store already seen values and cleanup them with `uniqBy`, and get only needed ones with `differenceBy` for each loop cycle.

Here is how it could look:

```
_.map(items, item => _.reduce(
  _.toPairs(item),
  ({ seenValues, result }, [key, values]) => ({
    seenValues: _.uniqBy([...seenValues, ...values], 'no'),
    result: {
      ...result,
      [key]: _.take(_.differenceBy(values, seenValues, 'no'), 4)
    }
  }),
  { seenValues: [], result: {} }
));
```

We use `toPairs` to have that unpacked `key` and `value` in reduce function, so we can costruct needed structure back.

At the end you can just get the `result` property. Check this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/tikoyehapi/1/edit?js,console for more.